# Why Does Community Close Questions?

Tags: discussion

I voted to close [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121326/using-custom-labels-in-comparable-text) as duplicate, and before anyone else voted on it, the [Community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user backed up my vote. Apparently they can dupe hammer as if they had a gold badge. Under what circumstances does this situation occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Community bot closes duplicates when the author of the question confirms that it is a duplicate. It is able to close at once because it has a moderator status (a diamond next to its name).

See [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981)